# Java: Check if a string could be properly encoded using given charset?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

How to check if a string could be properly (without loss of information) encoded with a given *charset*?

The obvious way is to convert to the target encoding, decode back and compare. Is there are a smarter way?

**P.S.** Practical application is to use 8-bit encoding for a large text file filtering out strings that could not be encoded given the charset. (They could be kept in a separate UTF-8 file if needed).

**Naïve solution:**

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class NaiveCharsetValidatation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Charset targetCharset = Charset.forName("iso-8859-1");

        byte[] bytes = "ภาษาไทย".getBytes(targetCharset);

        String decodedString = new String(bytes, targetCharset);

        System.out.println(decodedString); // outputs ???????
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonK Please check the solution (added to the original post).

Comment: @JonK, what he proposes would work just fine (even if he's looking for something faster). When you first convert to the target encoding, any character that doesn't have a representation in that encoding will either be missing or turned into some sort of missing-character marker (like '?', or �). When you convert back to the original encoding after that, the strings definitely won't match anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The method you propose is the most straight-forward way for the general case of any encoding to any other encoding. If, however, you know easy-to-test attributes, the test can be done faster. For instance, if you want to encode to ISO-88591-1, for example, you can simply look for any character with a codepoint greater than 0xFF. For ASCII, any code point greater than 0x7F.

A simple regex will accomplish this kind of test. You can also use a regex to test for a number of character ranges, if it's easy enough to find a few spans of codepoints that wouldn't translate.

If this regex is true:

`/[^\x00-\xFF]/`

Any matching string can't be converted to ISO-8859-1 without loss.

That would be `Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\xFF]")` for Java.

(I've been out of doing Java and instead doing TypeScript/JavaScript for so long I'm not used to Java regex syntax any more!)

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a string can be represented properly in a specific character encoding, by trying encoding/decoding.

For example:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (canBeConvertedToStringEncoding("abc", "ISO-8859-1")) {
      System.out.println("can be converted");
    } else {
      System.out.println("cannot be converted");
    }

    if (canBeConvertedToStringEncoding("あいう", "ISO-8859-1")) {
      System.out.println("can be converted");
    } else {
      System.out.println("cannot be converted");
    }
  }

  public static boolean canBeConvertedToStringEncoding(String target, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String to = new String(target.getBytes(encoding), encoding);
    if (target.equals(to)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```